# Wiring a Lorenzetti shower heater

Tags: power-supply, wiring

the shower unit reads: 220v-5500 30A 4mm<sup>2</sup>/10AWG .

The present wire installation is 30A breaker with #10 wire for about 30 feet, connected to #12 wire for another 6’ to the shower head.

1. Can I use this shower unit on 110?.
2. with 20 or 30 Amp breaker?
3. With the same wire installation?

Comment: A picture of the name plate on the heater, a link to the instructions, and a picture of the heater itself, all [edit]ed into the question would help a lot.

Comment: If I add another 6’ of #10 to the shower head, instead of the #12 is that a solution?

Comment: Where are you? Electrical service is 120/240V in the U.S. I assume you wouldn't have mentioned 110 if you weren't in the U.S. Is your unit intended for the Euro market? Specs of 220V are not common (though 230 is).

Comment: You can't upload images until you have some reputation. Upload to somewhere else and put a link in your post.

Comment: Im in Costa Rica.  These are made in Brazil, same standards as USA.  They used to make a 110 unit, now they are all 220.  I don’t need HOT water, just to take the chill out of the water.  So 2250watts would be more than enough.

Comment: Here is the web page.  Click on technical Information.  I don’t understand it.  
https://www.lorenzetti.com.br/en/product/maxi-ducha-258

Comment: On 110/120, you'd only get 1350W (Half the volts, so half the current, so one quarter the power.)

Comment: Thank you.  I think that is all I need.